# Matching alphanumeric characters separated by spaces

Tags: php, regex

Okay, I'm stuck. PHP, Regex. I have a string:

`Это кириллические 23 78these are56 45latin76 letters here98 85 буквы.`

And I want to use preg_replace() to enclose a substring containing latin letters, numbers and spaces with <b> tags. A substring is not merely a word but a set of words as long as the next word contains Latin characters:

Это кириллические 23 **78these are56 45latin76 letters here98** 85 буквы.

My best shot was:

```
$text = 'Это кириллические 23 78these are56 45latin76 letters here98 85 буквы.';
$regex = "/\d*\p{Latin}+(\d|\s|\p{Latin})*/iu";
preg_replace($regex, '<b>$0</b>', $text);
```

But it grabs not only "here98" but also the following "85":

Это кириллические 23 **78these are56 45latin76 letters here98 85** буквы.

I understand why it is so but fail to figure out the correct Regex.

Comment: @TheJumpingFrog , [A-z0-9] doesn't take spaces into account. I need to have something like <b>bla34 64bla</b> and not <b>bla34</b> <b>64bla</b>.

Comment: `([A-z0-9]|\s)` will that take blank space?

Comment: @TheJumpingFrog `/[A-z]/i` will also match chars from `Z` to `a`, i.e.: "[\\]^\_\`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not just match Latin+digits words, but look one word ahead and one word behind.
AFAIK, variable-length look-behinds are not possible, so you should use non-capturing group `(?:...)`and positive look-ahead `(?=...)`:

```
$regex = "/(?:[\p{Latin}\d]+ )([\p{Latin}\d ]+)(?= [\p{Latin}\d]+)/iu";
preg_replace($regex, '<b>$1</b>', $text);
```

PS: Aaaah! Russian mafia! ;-)

Comment: Oh yesss. It worksss, my precioussss. I've always been lousy with lookaheads no wonder I couldn't use them properly when time came. I'm actually doing this task for Katakana/Hiragana/Kanji, Cyrillic and Latin letters are just easier to use in examples. Arigatou gozaimasu to Russian mafia. :-)